# How can I get this type of interpolation

Tags: interpolation

[image]

As shown in the figure, it should be a specific value

Comment: Please show your code, not a picture!

Comment: Do you want to know how to interpolate correctly or why that particular result was obtained? Your question is not clear. What have you done to get to this point?

Comment: I got it by typing the numbers surrounded by `[]` next to the interpolating function (i.e., plugging in the numbers): https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtuMs.png

Answer (score 1):

For example in this way

```
pi = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 3}]; (*some points in 3D*)
```

If you want to assign a scalar value for aevery point pi , `Interpolation` expects a dataseet in the form `{{{x1,x2,x3},scalar},...}`

```
ip = Interpolation[Map[{#, # . #} &, pi] , InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

[image]